# Mac OSx - Sever error 500 after creating new PHP.ini

Tags: php, macos, apc

I recently installed APC extensions for my default PHP installation. To facilitate the loading of this new extension I created a new php.ini in /private/etc/

So now this location contains both the new php.ini and the default, php.ini.default. The new php.ini is just a copy of the default one but with the added extension being loading in the dynamic extensions section.

When I attempt to access any page in my local/host/~username virtual directory I receive a server 500 error.

I viewed the logs located in /var/log/apache2/ but I don't see any log of a server 500 error.

I suspect that this error might be related to my having both the default and the new php.ini in the same directory.

Has anyone had this problem? Should I remove / rename the default configuration file?

This is the line that I added to the Dynamic Extensions section of php.ini

```
vim extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so
```

Comment: Can you post the specific lines you added to `php.ini`? Also, I have both `php.ini` and `php.ini.default` in `/etc` so I think it's not causing the issue.

Comment: System administration questions belong on http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: I appended the line to my post.

Comment: `vim extension` is not a valid php.ini directive. it'd be just `extension = ...`. vim is a text editor, not a php thing.

Comment: Oh geez.. Yes that's what I have. I copied that from my term. Thanks